# logical replication issue: increasing wal files and replication lag

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 PostgreSQL 16 instances in different location and I am trying to apply logical replication between couple of tables even there are thousands of tables in publisher site. I mean there are about 5000 tables in publisher site but I am using logical replication for only 60 tables

All the replicated tables are in sync as number of record count currently. I have checked with select count(*) from table

My problem is when I run following query I could see increasing huge replication lag and number of files in WAL directory increasing (number of wal files are 9952)
If I drop subscription and replication slot, postgresql cleaning WAL directory

```
# SELECT

slot_name,
    confirmed_flush_lsn,
    pg_current_wal_lsn(),
    (pg_current_wal_lsn() - confirmed_flush_lsn) AS lag
FROM pg_replication_slots;
                 slot_name                 | confirmed_flush_lsn | pg_current_wal_lsn |     lag      
-------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------
 log_rep_slot                              | 6C5/2C77D4E0        | 6E7/F6A54B40       | 149420865120
 pg_316283_sync_248141_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248213_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248175_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248194_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248206_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248232_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248159_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248147_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248129_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
 pg_316283_sync_248165_7306809026670557899 |                     | 6E7/F6A54B40       |             
(11 rows)
```

So why WAL files and replication lag are increasing even if all my replicated tables are in sync

Comment: `All the replicated tables are in sync` - the presence of pg_316283_sync_* indicates the opposite - the initial datasync is in progress. Check the logs, pg_stat_subscription and `select srrelid::regclass, srsubstate from pg_subscription_rel`

Comment: there is no sync process currently but WAL size in publisher still increasing

select srrelid::regclass, srsubstate from pg_subscription_rel      --> all tables are in r state

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you have long running transactions on the publisher, and you didn't define the subscription with `streaming = parallel`.

But wait a minute: you still have some workers running that copy original table contents.  Replication won't start until they are done.  Perhaps you should start replication with a few tables and then use `ALTER PUBLICATION` and `ALTER SUBSCRIPTION ... REFRESH PUBLICATION` to add more tables little by little.

Once the table sync workers are done, replication should start to catch up (check `restart_lsn` in `pg_replication_slots`). If logical decoding is too slow for your rate of WAL creation, increase `logical_decoding_work_mem` on the publisher.  If that is not sufficient, you are out of luck, and logical replication won't work for you. If it is the subscriber that is too slow applying the changes, you can split the workload to several publications and subscriptions, or you can try to increase `max_parallel_apply_workers_per_subscription` on the subscriber.

Comment: checked long running transaction, there is not. Longest transaction is about 40-50 minutes

Comment: what setting do you recommend streaming=on or streaming=parallel

I want to clean out pg_wal in ASAP

Comment: Well, 40 minutes is a very, _very_, *very* long running transaction. I guess `parallel` would be the best value.

Comment: when I add new table to publication, I always run alter subscription <subsName> refresh publication 

I altered subscription with streaming = parallel and number of wal files are still increasing

Comment: Great! Did you check that all sync workers were dune?

Comment: there are 10 sync process like following
 pg_316283_sync_248194_7306809026670557899 | 6E8/EB4C1830        | 6EC/3AAB0000       |  14216521680

the last value in output is lag

Comment: You have to wait until all those sync workers are done. Only then replication will start. WAL is retained on the primary until all the sync workers are done.

Comment: if sync worker process are running why sync worker process's lags are increasing ?

Comment: Let me repeat it: replication will only start once copying the data is completed. The publisher has to keep all WAL until copying the data is done. Only then the subscriber will start replicating, and only then will the publisher be able to delete WAL.

Comment: started logical replication over again with following command  (because of the disk space problem on publisher)

`create subscription sub1 CONNECTION '<host connection parameters>'
publication pub1
with (create_slot = true, slot_name = 'log_rep_slot', binary=true, streaming='parallel');` 


now sync workers done but number of WAL files and replication lag still increasing again

Comment: postgres=# SELECT

slot_name,
    confirmed_flush_lsn,
    pg_current_wal_lsn(),
    (pg_current_wal_lsn() - confirmed_flush_lsn) AS lag
FROM pg_replication_slots;
  slot_name   | confirmed_flush_lsn | pg_current_wal_lsn |     lag     
--------------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------
 log_rep_slot | 6F0/C09E1D28        | 6F5/6437DF40       | 19924632088

Comment: Do the `restart_lsn` and `catalog_xmin` grow? With 40 minute transactions and lots of data modifications, you might just be out of luck.

Comment: Run following query in every 10 minutes

SELECT                                                              

slot_name,restart_lsn,catalog_xmin,
    confirmed_flush_lsn,
    pg_current_wal_lsn(),
    (pg_current_wal_lsn() - confirmed_flush_lsn) AS lag
FROM pg_replication_slots;

In 75 mins period
--> LAG value increased from 23385676888 to 51470074704
--> catalog_xmin did not change
--> restart_lsn did not change 
--> confirmed_flush_lsn did not change
--> pg_current_wal_lsn changed from 6F6/9A622000 to 6FD/4C39A000

Comment: Well, then I am out of guesses.